# Delete columns with cells with the conditional formatting red

Tags: excel, vba

I plan to conditional format cells in row 18 then clear the columns with the red cells.

This code deletes columns when I fill in a cell with red but not when I use conditional formatting.

```vb
Sub sbDelete_Columns_Based_On_Cell_Color()
    Dim lColumn As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long

    lColumn = 50
    For iCntr = lColumn To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(18, iCntr).Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbRed Then
            Columns(iCntr).Delete
        End If
    Next iCntr
End Sub
```

Comment: `Cells(18, iCntr).DISPLAYFORMAT.Interior.Color`

Comment: Your conditional formatting rule is using some kind of logic to highlight cells red so just use that exact same logic here. You are using conditional formatting as a middle man. Skip the middle man, code your logic here in VBA

Answer (score 1):

Using the below code you can scrape cell color from conditional formatting:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Color As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
        Color = .Range("D1").DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```